# How to check datatype of variable in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am not able to check datatype in robot framework. I want to evaluate datatype of a variable.

e.g.

```
${variable}    123
```

Now I need to check if the `${variable}` value here is integer or not. I tried using evaluate but it gives data structure.

Answer (score 17):

You can get the type of a variable by using the method `type()`, inside an Evaluate keyword; be sure to pass a reference to the variable itself:

```
${type string}=    Evaluate     type($variable)
Log To Console     ${type string}
```

The output is a bit specific, it will be similar to this:

```
<class 'int'>
```

If you want just the "int" part in it, get its `__name__` property:

```
${type string}=    Evaluate     type($variable).__name__
```

Then it will be just this - `'int'`.

And if you want to check is a variable of specific type (or in general, in python, a subclass of another), you can use `isinstance()`:

```
${is int}=      Evaluate     isinstance($variable, int)    # will be True
${is string}=   Evaluate     isinstance($variable, str)    # will be False
```

*(the last example assumes your `${variable}` is an actual integer)*

Comment: thanks @Todor Minakov I tried doing it however it shows unicode. So is this how robot framework show datatype or should it be int?

Comment: It really depends on how you created the variable. By default all variables created with `Set Variable` are strings - if you typed `${variable}    Set Variable    123`, the type of that variable is going to be string - a string with the value "123", which though looks like a number is really a string (you can do `Fetch From Left` on it, for example). If you want to create a "true" number variable, surround it in curly brackets - `${variable}    Set Variable    ${123}`. By the way, unrelated - you use python 2, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the Evaluate and type keyword but it was giving the error at the $ character. Then I used the curly parenthesis and then it worked.

${param_type}=    Evaluate    type(${json_value})

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems checking json strings, because Robot will replace the value and python will try to Evaluate the expression. I found this to be a better way to check the types:

```
${is_type} =    Evaluate    "${variable.__class__.__name__}" == "str"
```

str was just an example,you can check any type there. You can also check for subclasses like this:

```
${is_subclass} =    Evaluate    issubclass($variable.__class__}, ClassNameHere)
```

Check the difference between using ${variable} and $variable here:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-variables-1

Edit: Using issubclass(type($variable), dict) also works.